# Der Mann sieht heiß aus

Tags: colloquial

While I am aware of the secondary meaning of 'heiß' as 'sexy', it seems conceivable that we could say, ,Der Mann sieht heiß aus.', if the surrounding conditions were right, i.e., it is 40+ degrees out and the man is sweating? Grammatisch gesehen ist's richtig, oder nicht?

Likewise, ,Die Frau sieht kalt aus.'

Or, is it necessary in these two cases to be roundabout and say, 'Der Mann gibt mir den Eindruck, dass es ihm heiß ist.'?

Answer (score 5):

Apart from making a pun saying "Der Mann sieht heiß aus" will always be understood "that man is hot/attractive".

You can say

> Es sieht aus, als wäre dem Mann ziemlich heiß/warm/kalt.

For cold feelings you can also use the verb *frieren*

> Der Mann friert / Der Mann sieht aus, als würde er frieren.

However, apart from *schwitzen* German offers no pendant to *frieren* for warm/hot temperatures.

A really short version would be to say

> Dem Mann ist heiß/kalt/warm.

or

> Dem Mann muss (wirklich) heiß/kalt/warm sein

Comment: Auch: Dem Mann scheint warm zu sein

Comment: Aber Vorsicht mit "Der Mann scheint warm zu sein"